# Windows 8 Metro record audio (filter noise, change pitch)

Tags: c#, audio, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to record audio only when there is someone talking? I want to listen to the microphone and only start recording when the "volume" is greater than some noise level (meaning someone is talking) I also need to change the pitch of the recorded audio.

I tried MediaCapture class in C# but StartRecordToStorageFileAsync from a sample is not useable in my scenario. In Windows Phone I use XNA but I cannot find a similiar API in Windows 8.

Comment: how did you get your hands on windows 8 ;) ?

Comment: @Sam1 - It is in its 'consumer preview' stage? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/consumer-preview?SignedIn=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this thread on MSDN forums: [How to get the decibel with C#?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/f04e0629-2609-4542-a141-46166f4cbdeb)

It seems like there is and probably will not be APIs for doing that in C#, Visual Basic or JavaScript and you need to do it in a native component.

The Core Audio/WASAPI APIs from the article mentioned in that thread should have what you need: [Win32 and COM for Metro style apps (multimedia)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452756.aspx)

I think [this document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/9/9/F99791F2-D5BE-478A-B77A-830AD14950C3/AudioCaptureRaw_Walkthrough.pdf) has a description of a sample for capturing audio from a Kinect sensor that might have relevant code samples showing how you would use GetBuffer() calls to get the buffer of raw audio samples that you could process to get the information you need.

Comment: That sample probably won't work in Metro -- it requires using APIs that are not supported in Metro style applications (e.g. IMMDevice)

Comment: Sure, but parts of it should be helpful. I could not find one good for metro style apps.

Comment: I would do anything to avoid using the C++ API. 500ms delay mentioned in the article is not a problem for me. My idea is to use StartRecordToStreamAsync to record audio to a stream permanently and maybe use a timer to periodicaly check the stream if the volume is higher than something (someone speeking) and end when it is back to none speeking. I would get me two positions in the stream and I will cout the part of the stream out and use it. Can I do this? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe there is some way to do MediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync and read the stream while it is being written to. Otherwise - You would probably need to do at least a thin C++ WinRT Component that would allow you to process everything in C# and once you get there - you might decide to do most of that code in C++ anyway. From my experience - yes, it is good if you can avoid getting into C++ - I found it some 5 times less productive than C#, but I think it is an investment you have to make if you are thinking about building anything nice on WinRT.

Comment: @IgorKulman, did you find a way to accomplish the simultaneous read/write on a single stream? I am in the same boat and would really appreciate the benefit of any lessons you have learned in your attempts. Thanks!